# Javascript: Find max value of attribute in objects and if equal return string

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a solution for my Problem:

First I have an Javascript Object

```
var obj = {
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  20,
    'Section C':  10
}
```

I want to get the highest number and key of the object:

```
var max= Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var max_key=undefined;

for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key] > max)
        {
            max_key = key;
            max = obj[key];
        }
}

document.getElementById('explain').innerText = "max is: "+max_key+" with: "+max+" points";
```

This gives me Section B with 20 Points...

But im looking also for a solution when the object is like:

```
var obj = {
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  10,
    'Section C':  10
}
document.getElementById('explain').innerText = "There is no maximum";
```

Or

```
var obj = {
    'Section A':  20,
    'Section B':  20,
    'Section C':  10
}
document.getElementById('explain').innerText = "Section A and B are equal";
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work perfectly fine, if you add this line after finding out the maximum points:

```
let winner = Object.keys(obj).filter(o => obj[o] == max);
```

This will give you an array of all the keys with who have scored maximum points.

However, I've a more generic solution to your problem:

```
var obj = {
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  20,
    'Section C':  10
};

let max = Object.values(obj).reduce(function(a, b) { return Math. max(a, b); });
let winners = Object.keys(obj).filter(o => obj[o] == 10);
console.log(winners);
```

You can add your conditions to this piece of code and get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce with an array and get the minimum for not having a maximum.

```js
function getMaximum(object) {
    function nice([...array]) {
        return array.concat(array.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', ');
    }

    let
        min = Number.MAX_VALUE,
        entries = Object.entries(object),
        result = entries.reduce((r, [key, max]) => {
            min = Math.min(min, max);
            if (max > r[0].max) return [{ key, max }];
            else if (max === r[0].max) r.push({ key, max });
            return r;
        }, [{ max: -Number.MAX_VALUE }]);

    if (min === result[0].max) {
        return 'There is no maximum';
    }
    if (result.length === 1) {
        return `max is: ${result[0].key} with: ${result[0].max} points`;
    }
    return `Section ${nice(result.map(({ key }) => key))} are equal with ${result[0].max} points.`
}

console.log(getMaximum({ 'Section A': 10, 'Section B': 20, 'Section C': 10 }));  // B 20
console.log(getMaximum({ 'Section A': 10, 'Section B': 10, 'Section C': 10 })); // "There is no maximum";
console.log(getMaximum({ 'Section A': 20, 'Section B': 20, 'Section C': 10 })); // "Section A and B are equal";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast and efficient solution:

```js
var obj = {
    'Section A': 70,
    'Section B': 10,
    'Section C': 70
}

var maxKeyValues = [];
let res = "";

let max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

let noMax = true,
    prevValue = undefined;

for (var key in obj) {
    prevValue = prevValue ? prevValue : obj[key];
    if (obj[key] !== prevValue) {
        noMax = false;
    }
    prevValue = obj[key];
    if (obj[key] > max) {
        maxKeyValues = [{ key: key, value: obj[key] }];
        max = obj[key];
    }
    else if (obj[key] === max) {
        maxKeyValues.push({ key: key, value: obj[key] });
    }
}

if (noMax)
    res = "there is no maximum";

else
    res = maxKeyValues.length === 1 ? "max is: " + maxKeyValues[0].key + " with: " + maxKeyValues[0].value + " points" :
    maxKeyValues.reduce((prev, curr) => prev ? prev + " and " + curr.key : curr.key, "") + " are equal with " + maxKeyValues[0].value + " points";

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. find all values…
2. find the maxium of those values
3. find the max entries in obj
4. return result

```js
var obj1 = {
  'Section A': 10,
  'Section B': 20,
  'Section C': 10
};

var obj2 = {
  'Section A': 10,
  'Section B': 10,
  'Section C': 10
};

var obj3 = {
  'Section A': 20,
  'Section B': 20,
  'Section C': 10,
  'Section D': 20
};


function getMax(obj) {
  // 1. find all values…
  const values = Object.values(obj);

  // 2. find the maxium of those values
  const maxValue = Math.max(...values);

  // 3. find the max entries in obj
  const maxObj = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value === maxValue);

  // 4.a case where there is only one max
  if (maxObj.length === 1) {
    const [key, value] = maxObj[0];
    return `max is: ${key} with: ${value} points`;
  }

  // 4.b case where all entries have the same value
  if (maxObj.length === values.length) {
    return 'There is no maximum';
  }

  // 4.c case where there are multiple max
  return maxObj.reduce((list, [key], index) => {
    list += index !== 0 ? (index === maxObj.length - 1 ? ' and ' : ', ') : '';
    list += key;
    return list;
  }, '') + ` are equal with ${maxObj[0][1]} points`;
}

console.log(getMax(obj1));
console.log(getMax(obj2));
console.log(getMax(obj3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
getMax = function (obj) {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj)
    const accmax = ([ks, mv], [k, v]) => 
        v > mv ? [[k], v] 
        : v == mv ? [[...ks, k], mv] 
        : [ks, mv]
    const text = ([ks, mv]) => 
        ks.length == entries.length ? "There is no maximum"
        : ks.length > 1 ? ks.join(" and ") + " are equal"
        : `max is: ${ks[0]} with: ${mv} points`
    return text(entries.reduce(accmax, [[], -Infinity]))
}
```

Advantages:

- Find both max value and keys in just one iteration.
- Generates the expected text based on the results.

Answer (score 0):

As to propose another approach, you can make one that always finds an array of maximum keys.

It's pretty similar to your code:

```js
function findMaxKeys(obj){
  var max = -Infinity;
  var max_keys = [];

  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key] === max){     //Another key with the same value
      max_keys.push(key);     //Add it to the array
    }else if(obj[key] > max){ //Found a bigger key, start over...
      max_keys = [key];       //Replace the array
      max = obj[key];
    }        
  }
  return max_keys;
}

console.log(findMaxKeys({
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  20,
    'Section C':  10
})) // ['Section B']

console.log(findMaxKeys({
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  10,
    'Section C':  10
})) // ['Section A', 'Section B', 'Section C']

console.log(findMaxKeys({})) // []
```

This will run a single pass through the array, so it's a fast solution.

However, note that `for..in` is often not the best way to iterate over an object. You can also change this approach to use another iteration method, e.g. `Object.entries()`:

```js
function findMaxKeys(obj){
  let max = -Infinity;
  let max_keys = [];

  for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(val === max){     //Another key with the same value
      max_keys.push(key);     //Add it to the array
    }else if(val > max){ //Found a bigger key, start over...
      max_keys = [key];       //Replace the array
      max = val;
    }        
  }
  return max_keys;
}

console.log(findMaxKeys({
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  20,
    'Section C':  10
})) // ['Section B']

console.log(findMaxKeys({
    'Section A':  10,
    'Section B':  10,
    'Section C':  10
})) // ['Section A', 'Section B', 'Section C']

console.log(findMaxKeys({})) // []
```